# python3 reset stdin after end of file

Tags: python-3.x, stdin, eof

On Linux, I want to read from `stdin` where `stdin` comes first from pipe and then from user input.
So the command looks like:

```
cat my-file | ./my-prog.py
```

After reading all the lines from the pipe:

```
inf = open(0, "r")
inf.readlines()
```

I want to get further input from user. I do it with `input()`. But I get `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`.
I need a way to reset the `stdin` before the call to `input()`.
Trying `sys.stdin.seek(0)` gives

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: underlying stream is not seekable
```

I read that in `c` there is `clearerr` that do that but I was not able to find how to do it in python.